# r- how to store the result of boxtidwell into a data frame/matrix

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'd like to store the result of the boxtidwell in order to write some code to achieve automation and avoid manually transform the variables. See example below:

```
 >boxTidwell(prestige ~ income + education, ~ type + poly(women, 2), data = Prestige) 

 ##            Score Statistic   p-value MLE of lambda
 ## income          -4.482406 0.0000074    -0.3476283
 ## education        0.216991 0.8282154     1.2538274 
 ## iterations =  8
```

Because I do not want to transform the variable manually such as the code below:

```
 >Prestige$income <- (Prestige$income )^(-0.3476283)
```

When there are many variables need to be transformed then it will be so time-consuming. I tried matrix and data.frame but both in vain.

```
> box<-boxTidwell(prestige ~ income + education, ~ type + poly(women, 2),   data = Prestige)
> box<-as.data.frame(box)

#Error in as.data.frame.default(box) : 
#cannot coerce class ""boxTidwell"" to a data.frame

> box<-as.matrix(box)
> box

#Error in round(x$result, digits) : 
#non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I've searched for a while but seems in vain, many thanks for any suggestions and ideas in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's accessible in `box$result`, e.g.

```
box$result[,"MLE of lambda"]

    income  education 
-0.3476283  1.2538274
```

so your code above becomes (crudely)
`Prestige$income <- (Prestige$income )^box$result[1,3]`

In general, to check out what's inside your object use `str`

Comment: Thanks, it's useful. However, is there still room for improvement? For example, we shall be able to avoid manually type the variable name `"income"` (i.e:`Prestige$income`) in your code. It should be more general way like this: `Prestige$result[1,0]<- (Prestige$income )^box$result[1,3]`.  Since it might be many variables need to transform and we cannot type all variables by hand.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You have access to the entire matrix of variables in `box$result`. It has 2 rows and 3 columns and you can index it however you want.